# Plot horizontal bar chart with "nice alignment" of label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the following code. But in my Y axis I want labels as `feature_1`, `feature_2` etc. But, when I am plotting the labels are not clear. It is congested. Can anyone help me out.

```
"""
Simple demo of a horizontal bar chart.
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Example data

important_features = [(0.0457, 'feat_34'), (0.042, 'feat_11'), (0.0359, 'feat_25'), (0.0355, 'feat_60'), (0.0316, 'feat_40'), (0.0298, 'feat_14'), (0.0272, 'feat_80'), (0.0252, 'feat_42'), (0.0241, 'feat_86'), (0.0236, 'feat_67'), (0.0232, 'feat_15'), (0.0217, 'feat_62'), (0.02, 'feat_24'), (0.0196, 'feat_26'), (0.0191, 'feat_54'), (0.0189, 'feat_36'), (0.0183, 'feat_48'), (0.0177, 'feat_75'), (0.016, 'feat_88'), (0.0155, 'feat_64'), (0.0147, 'feat_90'), (0.014, 'feat_72'), (0.014, 'feat_69'), (0.0131, 'feat_9'), (0.0131, 'feat_8'), (0.0131, 'feat_57'), (0.0129, 'feat_43'), (0.0126, 'feat_32'), (0.0126, 'feat_16'), (0.012, 'feat_76'), (0.0117, 'feat_33'), (0.0109, 'feat_68'), (0.0109, 'feat_4'), (0.0107, 'feat_39'), (0.0106, 'feat_70'), (0.0104, 'feat_78'), (0.0103, 'feat_59'), (0.0101, 'feat_53'), (0.0096, 'feat_85'), (0.0087, 'feat_38'), (0.0086, 'feat_47'), (0.0083, 'feat_50'), (0.0083, 'feat_46'), (0.0079, 'feat_92'), (0.0078, 'feat_71'), (0.0078, 'feat_30'), (0.0076, 'feat_17'), (0.0073, 'feat_66'), (0.007, 'feat_41'), (0.0069, 'feat_13'), (0.0068, 'feat_83'), (0.0068, 'feat_73'), (0.0068, 'feat_56'), (0.0066, 'feat_20'), (0.0064, 'feat_1'), (0.0062, 'feat_37'), (0.0061, 'feat_27'), (0.006, 'feat_87'), (0.006, 'feat_2'), (0.0058, 'feat_58'), (0.0058, 'feat_35'), (0.0058, 'feat_22'), (0.0056, 'feat_18'), (0.0055, 'feat_55'), (0.0054, 'feat_74'), (0.0053, 'feat_91'), (0.0053, 'feat_79'), (0.005, 'feat_29'), (0.0049, 'feat_44'), (0.0046, 'feat_89'), (0.0045, 'feat_45'), (0.0041, 'feat_10'), (0.0039, 'feat_19'), (0.0037, 'feat_21'), (0.0035, 'feat_3'), (0.0033, 'feat_65'), (0.0031, 'feat_7'), (0.003, 'feat_23'), (0.0029, 'feat_63'), (0.0029, 'feat_52'), (0.0028, 'feat_77'), (0.0027, 'feat_49'), (0.0025, 'feat_12'), (0.0022, 'feat_93'), (0.0021, 'feat_28'), (0.002, 'feat_61'), (0.002, 'feat_5'), (0.0019, 'feat_81'), (0.0017, 'feat_31'), (0.0011, 'feat_84'), (0.0011, 'feat_51'), (0.0009, 'feat_82'), (0.0009, 'feat_6')]

x_value = []
y_feat = []
for (a, b) in important_features:
    y_feat.append(b)
    x_value.append(a)

features = y_feat
y_pos = range(1,2*len(features),2)

performance = x_value


plt.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(y_pos, features)
plt.ylim(0,200)
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.title('Feature Plot')

plt.show()
```

Comment: the obvious solutions: make the figure bigger, the font smaller, plot less bars

Comment: @JulienSpronck - Can you please help me out, how to do that .?

Comment: fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 20))                                                                        Change 10 and 20 accordingly. it represents x and y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do. There are simply too many bars, so the text is on top of each other. My solution is to put half of them on the left of the bar the other half on the right of the bar (you can change that to wherever you want them to be but the idea is to put half of them somewhere and the other half somewhere else). Also, making the figure bigger helps.

```
"""
Simple demo of a horizontal bar chart.
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Example data

important_features = [(0.0457, 'feat_34'), (0.042, 'feat_11'), (0.0359, 'feat_25'), (0.0355, 'feat_60'), (0.0316, 'feat_40'), (0.0298, 'feat_14'), (0.0272, 'feat_80'), (0.0252, 'feat_42'), (0.0241, 'feat_86'), (0.0236, 'feat_67'), (0.0232, 'feat_15'), (0.0217, 'feat_62'), (0.02, 'feat_24'), (0.0196, 'feat_26'), (0.0191, 'feat_54'), (0.0189, 'feat_36'), (0.0183, 'feat_48'), (0.0177, 'feat_75'), (0.016, 'feat_88'), (0.0155, 'feat_64'), (0.0147, 'feat_90'), (0.014, 'feat_72'), (0.014, 'feat_69'), (0.0131, 'feat_9'), (0.0131, 'feat_8'), (0.0131, 'feat_57'), (0.0129, 'feat_43'), (0.0126, 'feat_32'), (0.0126, 'feat_16'), (0.012, 'feat_76'), (0.0117, 'feat_33'), (0.0109, 'feat_68'), (0.0109, 'feat_4'), (0.0107, 'feat_39'), (0.0106, 'feat_70'), (0.0104, 'feat_78'), (0.0103, 'feat_59'), (0.0101, 'feat_53'), (0.0096, 'feat_85'), (0.0087, 'feat_38'), (0.0086, 'feat_47'), (0.0083, 'feat_50'), (0.0083, 'feat_46'), (0.0079, 'feat_92'), (0.0078, 'feat_71'), (0.0078, 'feat_30'), (0.0076, 'feat_17'), (0.0073, 'feat_66'), (0.007, 'feat_41'), (0.0069, 'feat_13'), (0.0068, 'feat_83'), (0.0068, 'feat_73'), (0.0068, 'feat_56'), (0.0066, 'feat_20'), (0.0064, 'feat_1'), (0.0062, 'feat_37'), (0.0061, 'feat_27'), (0.006, 'feat_87'), (0.006, 'feat_2'), (0.0058, 'feat_58'), (0.0058, 'feat_35'), (0.0058, 'feat_22'), (0.0056, 'feat_18'), (0.0055, 'feat_55'), (0.0054, 'feat_74'), (0.0053, 'feat_91'), (0.0053, 'feat_79'), (0.005, 'feat_29'), (0.0049, 'feat_44'), (0.0046, 'feat_89'), (0.0045, 'feat_45'), (0.0041, 'feat_10'), (0.0039, 'feat_19'), (0.0037, 'feat_21'), (0.0035, 'feat_3'), (0.0033, 'feat_65'), (0.0031, 'feat_7'), (0.003, 'feat_23'), (0.0029, 'feat_63'), (0.0029, 'feat_52'), (0.0028, 'feat_77'), (0.0027, 'feat_49'), (0.0025, 'feat_12'), (0.0022, 'feat_93'), (0.0021, 'feat_28'), (0.002, 'feat_61'), (0.002, 'feat_5'), (0.0019, 'feat_81'), (0.0017, 'feat_31'), (0.0011, 'feat_84'), (0.0011, 'feat_51'), (0.0009, 'feat_82'), (0.0009, 'feat_6')]

x_value = []
y_feat = []
for (a, b) in important_features:
    y_feat.append(b)
    x_value.append(a)

features = y_feat
y_pos = range(1,2*len(features),2)

performance = x_value

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
plt.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.4)
# no ticks
plt.yticks([])
j = 0
for x, y, label in zip(performance, y_pos, features):
    if j % 2 == 0: # half of them on the left of the axes
        plt.text(-0.0003, y, label, horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center')
    else:          # half of them on the right of the bars
        plt.text(x+0.0003, y, label, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center')
    j +=1
plt.ylim(0,200)
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.title('Feature Plot')

plt.show()
```